# Changing GridSplitter Behavior When Grid Element is hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a table that has three horizontal elements and two gridsplitters between them:

- First Row is an Element
- Second row is Gridsplitter
- Third is an Element
- Fourth row is a GridSplitter
- Fifth row is an element

Now I want the third element (in between) to become invisible or height 0,
and a gridsplitter that will help me change size of Elements 1 and 5.

The table will look like

- First Row is an Element (before - 1)
- Second row is Gridsplitter
- Fifth row is an element (before - 5)

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Best Regards,
Ron

Comment: Have you tried any thing? Can you post your xaml?
You can actually Collapse the 3rd and 4th rows in case if you don't want using either code-behind or using a data trigger. So that only 1, 2 and 5th rows are visible.

Comment: We can able to help you more if you have tried something and post your xaml or try now and give us your inputs.